# vue - display only if array contains an object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a problem in my application.

I want to display my objects only, if they aren't `null`. This works pretty well for the following object:

```
this.val.descripiton ? [
  'descripiton', {
    label: 'label.val.descripiton',
  },
] : null,
```

I got a `string` from the API and thats why it works and if it's `null` - it's hidden.

But for the second object, I've a problem. Here I got an `array` from the API. The problem is that I always get this array, also when there are no values inside.

```
this.val.cities ? [
  'cities', {
    label: 'label.val.cities',
    display: cities => cities.join(', '),
  },
] && this.val.cities.length > 1 : null,
```

I want to check if the length is more than 1, if yes, display it. If no, hide it like the description. But I always get this error message in the console:

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `this.cities.length` should be `this.val.cities.length` and check in console it's array or object.

Comment: where are you using that code? please share the whole code

Comment: @Mr.Perfectionist I updated now the question. like this, I don't get anymore the error but I never got a value. So it's always hidden

Comment: I think @Alex gave you that answer. You have to put your logic before `?`

Comment: The solution from @Alex solved the error, but the `cities` are now always hidden - also when the array contains objects

Answer (score 2):

You've misplaced the length-check:

```
this.val.cities && this.val.cities.length > 1 ? [
  'cities', {
    label: 'label.val.cities',
    display: cities => cities.join(', '),
  },
] : null
```

Comment: with this solution, the error is solved but I it's always hidden.

Comment: Could be a problem in the template or in the remaining code. Please check your template or add it to the question.